# Is mocking meaningful in gmock if we do not involve real code?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, googlemock

I have been going over gmock examples written in the official documentation. I am puzzled by the fact that many of these examples do not involve the real code (that is, software under test). Instead, the examples just mock objects and only run methods on the mock objects directly. Here is an example taken from there:

```
using testing::ReturnPointee;
...
int x = 0;
MockFoo foo;
EXPECT_CALL(foo, GetValue())
  .WillRepeatedly(ReturnPointee(&x));  // Note the & here.
  x = 42;
EXPECT_EQ(42, foo.GetValue());  // This will succeed now.
```

I completely understand what the code is doing. But, why are we testing whether the mock code is behaving properly? I don't see any real code taking foo as a dependency injection. Is the involvement of real code intentionally omitted so as to focus on the mock aspect only?

Comment: You've taken the code entirely out of context; the context was "Returning Live Values from Mock Methods", and the code sample is used to demonstrate what happens. No more, no less.

Comment: Out of context? No attempt was made to take it out of context. It was merely an example I gave that showed a value coming out of a mock object was tested using a gtest macro EXPECT_EQ. But, as you said, I now also think it was used for demo only. I suppose you would agree that in a real test scenario, you would not test the mock object and instead use a real one?

Comment: Googlers like to literally speak in code. This often leads to confusion. EXPECT_EQ here is not meant as a unit test of anything (doing so would obviously be pointless), it's just another syntax for saying "if you'd call `foo.GetValue()` at this point, you'd get `42`". Of course in real life you'd call it from *your code under test*...

Comment: Thank you so so much rustyx! This is what I was hoping you'd write. I have no more issue with it. Happy Gmocking!